# XML doctype в OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: xml, openapi

Вопрос сравнительно простой: есть ли возможность описать *doctype*
исходящего *XML*-документа в *Schema Object* в моей
спецификации *OpenAPI 3.0*? Вижу, что есть некий
[*XML Object*](https://swagger.io/specification/#xml-object), но
он указывается только у свойств, и про *doctype* там ни
слова. Не упоминается оно и в статье
«[*Representing XML*](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/representing-xml/)». Неужели
это просто не поддерживается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В OpenAPI нет встроенного атрибута для DOCTYPE, но есть механизм [расширений](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/) - произвольных атрибутов с префиксом `x-`. Поэтому вы можете указать DOCTYPE в виде расширения, например:

```yaml
Customer:
  type: object
  properties:
    ...

  x-doctype: <!DOCTYPE customer SYSTEM "https://mycompany.com/dtd/customer.dtd">

  # или значение без обертки <!DOCTYPE ... >
  # x-doctype: customer SYSTEM "https://mycompany.com/dtd/customer.dtd"

  # или добавить расширение внутрь атрибута `xml`
  # xml:
  #  x-doctype: <!DOCTYPE customer SYSTEM "https://mycompany.com/dtd/customer.dtd">
```

или т.п.

Имейте ввиду, что расширения - это просто метаданные и инструменты (генераторы кода, валидаторы и др.) не обрабатывают неизвестные им расширения. Поэтому если нужно как-то обрабатывать это расширение, то его обработку придется реализовать самостоятельно.